# Get list of paying subscribers?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get a list of current **paying** subscribers from my YouTube channel who's payment method is still active?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?  doubt thats something thats available.

Comment: I don't see it specifically mentioned, which is why I am asking in case it is there but I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to get this information, but it does not matter anyways because as of December 1, 2017 YouTube will be discontinuing monthly paid subscriber service.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7515570

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions related topics for Youtube api is mentioned in [Subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions) and looking at the available methods, there is nothing mentioned about "*getting a list of current paying subscribers for your YouTube channel*", only getting a [list of subscribers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) in general.